# Applescript Google Translate

Tags: macos, applescript, google-translate, translate

The code works fine when the selected text is just one word but for more than one word it doesn't. I think spaces between words cause this problem yet I have no idea how to fix it.

```
on run {input, parameters}
 set phrase to input as string
 set phrase to quoted form of phrase

 set ui_lang to "en"
 set from_lang to "en"
 set to_lang to "tr"

 return "https://translate.google.com/?hl=" & ui_lang & "&sl=" & from_lang & "&tl=" & to_lang & "&text=" & phrase
```

end run

Comment: As I checked, the shown code works fine. So, it returns (proper) text URL. Now, what you does with this text URL in the next action of you workflow (service) ???

Comment: And... why do not simply replace **return** with **open location** to perform your translate directly?

Answer (score 0):

If it's to form part of the URL, then using `quoted form` will not work, as that prepares text intended for the shell.

For a web address, special characters, including the space, must be `url encoded`. Spaces are replaced with `%20` and other special characters have their own '%' code.

A quick and dirty method to solve this specific case involves replacing the spaces with '%20' by having these as your first three lines:

```
set phrase to input as string -- no changes
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"%20"}
set phrase to words of phrase as text
```

Basically, it breaks your string into words and rejoins them with %20 instead of spaces. It should work with a single word input as well. You should change the TID back to whatever (or the default {""}) in a subsequent line.

For example:

`"and empathetic programmers"` becomes `"and%20empathetic%20programmers"` which becomes `"https://translate.google/?hl=en&sl=en&tl=tr&text=and%20empathetic%20programmers"`

There are numerous questions on this site that discuss the subject, including some that are applescript-specific. You can also find more, including some handlers here: [Text Encoding | Decoding](http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-08.html) and [Encoding and Decoding Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/EncodeandDecodeText.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH51-SW1)

There is a lot written on this subject so it's an easy search. There are numerous online encoder/decoders as well, which you can use for testing comparisons.

Comment: I appreciate for your detailed information. Your dirty method worked fine for this short code and for more I am gonna visit links and search deeper.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set phrase to input as string
    
    set ui_lang to "en"
    set from_lang to "en"
    set to_lang to "tr"
    
    open location "https://translate.google.com/?hl=" & ui_lang & "&sl=" & from_lang & "&tl=" & to_lang & "&text=" & phrase
    
end run
```